# TLS 1.2 and Encrypt=true

Tags: asp.net, security, ssl, tls1.2

I've enabled TLS 1.2 in my DB server. Will it be automatically encrypt the Application to DB connection or I should add add encrypt=true in my ASP.NET connection string?